# Operator << overload in c++

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class obj
{
public:
 int i;
 friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, obj o);
}

void main()
{
 obj o;
 ofstream fout("data.txt");
 fout<<o;
 fout.close();
}
```

This is the my code, am getting error.
error : ostream : ambiguous symbol.

any one can help me.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the namespace. Prefix `ostream` with `std` - i.e. `std::ostream`

Also, you should pass the obj type by const reference to the operator:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const obj& o);
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't use namespace std (using namespace std is habit anyway) so the compiler doesn't know what on earth an ostream is.In addition to that, you didn't actually define operator<<, only declared it, so even if it recognizes it, it won't know what to do since you didn't tell it.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it you need to

- Add

  `using std::ostream;`
  `using std::ofstream;`
- Add a `;` after the class declaration
- Povide an implementation for the << operator.

In the end you should end up with something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using std::ostream;
using std::ofstream;

class obj
{
public:
 int i;
 friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const obj& o);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const obj& o)
{
  std::cout << o.i;
  return stream;
}

int main()
{
  obj o;
  ofstream fout("data.txt");
  fout << o;
  fout.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ofstream` is in namespace `std`, so you need to declare `fout` like this:

```
std::ofstream fout("data.txt");
```

I'll assume you simply omitted the definition of your operator<< function for simplicity.  Obviously, you'll need to write the body of that function for your next line to compile.

Answer (score 0):

ostream is a member of the std:: namespace, so either put a `using namespace std;` before your class declaration or explicitly refer to it with `std::ostream`.

Comment: `using std::ostream;` is another possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Consider passing your object in as a reference otherwise a new obj object will be created each time via the copy constructor.

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, obj& o);
```